# Switching to different animations does not work

Tags: rigging

For some weird reason I am in my walk pose.

[image]

But when I am in my running post, as you can see it has changed.

[image]

But for some reason he is still doing the walking animation, he is not running, nor are the other animations working. He is just walking, I don't know why is this happening?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi I have uploaded it

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=N765KxKQ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/N765KxKQ/)

Comment: If I open your file, open a Dopesheet window, switch it to Action Editor mode, I can go from an action to another and it works fine, it changes the action of the armature in the 3D view, so I'm not sure what's the problem...

Comment: HI, thanks for having a look at this. So when you changed from walking to running, on the dope sheet it does change to running but when I play it its still walking, not running. Is the same happening to you? What version of Blender are you using cause I am using Blender 2.8?

Comment: it's the 2019-05-22 version, yes I don't see any problem

Comment: How do I change to a running animation, I did that it is not working at all, I don't know what is wrong? Tell me all the steps you do to change to a running animation?